# Tools for converting text to logical form

Tags: semantics, formal-semantics, logical-form

What's the State of the Art in software for converting text to some sort of logical form?  Pros and con's of different packages approaches, if more than one exists?

Comment: I would imagine that the current state of the are is that, if anything does actually exist to do this, it is a research project. I'm assuming that 'logical form' means something rather more complicated than 'extracting the words and listing them alphabetically' which is a logical form but rather trivial.

Comment: There is [Blackburn & Bos' system](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/comsem/software1.html), which is a nice demonstration of how such an implementation can be done in principle, but by no means suited or even designed for real life applications, and even shows limitations on some comparatively simple toy examples.